# Is it possible to move prebid.js off the main thread?

Tags: prebid.js

My ad-supported single page web app is popular on phones. Unfortunately the Chrome/Lighthouse perfomance score takes a huge hit when prebid is included (85/100 down to 55/100)

I can't do without prebid obviously so I'm looking for ways to stop it blocking the main browser thread.  Any thoughts/insights on how to speed things up appreciated.

Comment: are you building prebid with "every/ all" adapters and modules etc? try to build with "just what need" to start.  I'm also guessing your using client side? maybe try prebid s2s, so any difference?

Comment: I'm just a publisher. I use an ad service. They use prebid. It's definitely all happening client side right now. I'll bug them about prebid S2S since that would clearly help (thanks for the tip - I didn't know it existed)

IMHO the header bidding industry needs to get their stuff out of the main thread as much as possible - It seriously impacts site visitor user experience.